# failed in count rows in php sql

Tags: php, mysql

Thank you in advance!
Please tell me! what is mistake in this code. I want to show total rows of sql on my site. I searched many of codes be like this but all failed. Please help me.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, 'sahiwalservices');

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "hunnysheikh99";

;

mysqli_select_db("sahiwalservices", $conn);

$result = mysqli_query("select count(1) FROM login");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$total = $row[0];
echo "Total rows: " . $total;

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: `mysqli_select_db("sahiwalservices", $conn);` invert those. Yet you don't need it neither. You're already using `($servername, $username, $password, 'sahiwalservices')`.

Comment: plus you never passed db connection here `$result = mysqli_query("select count(1) FROM login");`. RTM http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: In the procedural way, `mysqli_query()` function takes two parameters, first is your connection handler and second is your query string. RTM first, [http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: @RajdeepPaul GMTA ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- *Indeed :-)*

Answer (score 0):

Posting as a community wiki; I don't want rep from this.

[`mysqli_select_db()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php) - The syntax for that is:

- Db connection comes first
- Database name is second

Yet, you don't need that line since you're already passing that in:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, 'sahiwalservices');
```

Then, you didn't pass db connection to the query.

Example from the manual:

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT Name FROM City LIMIT 10"))
```

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Check for errors on the query also:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php